# My chat username is outdated and I can't chat despite being above the reputation threshold

Tags: bug, status-completed, chat

It is showing me as **user1112053** in chat and in my Stack Overflow profile it shows me as **Chirag Patel**.

I have 526 reputation, as seen here:

[image: screenshot of profile page]

but when I go to a chat room it doesn't allow me in. I was able to chat yesterday. I have since changed my display name and it's not showing my correct display name.

[image: screenshot of chat room]

Comment: at [SO chat page](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/) check whether you are shown as logged in

Comment: It is showing me as **user1112053** in chat and in SO Profile **Chirag Patel**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should now be fixed...we were throwing some errors this morning which caused a few downstream errors in chat, they're now resolved and things like this will start to recover (I just checked [your chat user page](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/users/1112053) to be sure).